# Copy data from SQL Server CE database file to another db file

Tags: sql-server-ce

I need to copy records from some tables of a SQL Server CE archive to another file using SQL query. With `.MDB` files I used the following query with success:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2 ...) IN 'path to new database' 
    SELECT field1, field2 ... 
    FROM tablename;
```

With SQL Server CE 3.5, this query fails.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first generate the INSERT statements and the run them against the new table. My SqlCeScripting API can help you with doing that programatically, and my SQL CE Toolbox graphically

Comment: Hi Erik, tank you for help me. Please what dou you mean with 'first generate the INSERT'. I've created the 2 files with the same tables structures before execute the insert command. Can you send me an example. Thank you very much,

Comment: You need to create INSERT statements for each row - see the sample here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/Scripting-API-samples